# Jquery Drag and drop form element to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am trying to build drag and drop form builder with Jquery UI , I have achieved below code, in this code  user drag form-group into demo area , now it is appending to demo div , 
It is working good for 1st element (input) to append from then it is appending random area

If I try to drag Button , it is not appending at all.

I want to achieve similar to http://bootsnipp.com/forms with Jquery UI only

How can I fix issues, what is wrong in my code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" id="catalog">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Input Text</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="demo" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; background-color: red">
            <label class="placeholder">Drag Elements in this area to build form</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="configuration">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




@section scripts {
     <script>
         $(function () {
             $("#catalog .form-group").draggable({
                 appendTo: ".demo",
                 helper: "clone"
             });
             $(".demo").droppable({
                 accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
                 drop: function (event, ui) {
                     $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
                     $(".demo").append($(".form-group").html());
                 }
             }).sortable({
                 items: "div:not(.placeholder)",
                 sort: function () {
                     // gets added unintentionally by droppable interacting with sortable
                     // using connectWithSortable fixes this, but doesn't allow you to customize active/hoverClass options
                     $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
                 }
             });

         });
     </script>
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/27L6a4vu/

Comment: Thanks  but why do we need to add a separate class for each , also how can I enable drag and drop  in demo container to re arrange and delete